# Pandas: get index of removed row

Tags: python, indexing, pandas

I have a large dataframe. Here is a small one for the example.

```
    C1  C2  C3  C4
0   foo one 1   4
1   foo one 1   5
2   foo two 2   3
3   bar one 3   6
4   bar two 2   7
```

I perform a list of filters that remove several rows. Here is the final df

```
    C1  C2  C3  C4
0   foo one 1   4
2   foo two 2   3
3   bar one 3   6
```

What I want is the index of the removed lines, so I can output all the values that were rejected.

Comment: can you first find the indices of the rows that need to be removed and then use `drop` to remove them?

Comment: I think you are looking for `index.difference`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use the [`difference`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/dev/generated/pandas.Index.difference.html) method on the two Index objects:

```
>>> df_orig.index.difference(df_final.index)
Int64Index([1, 4], dtype='int64')
```

If you're using a version of pandas without this, you could use `np.setdiff1d` instead:

```
>>> np.setdiff1d(df_orig.index, df_final.index)
array([1, 4], dtype=int64)
```

Answer (score 2):

Slightly different approach but same idea as DSM.

```
df.index[-df.index.isin(df1.index)]
```